# How to have an instance of an abstract type without me having to provide complete implementation?

Tags: scala

Is there a way to create an instance of a Java instance or a Scala trait without having to implement the abstract methods?

I'd like to have a `val c: java.sql.Connection` available in scope and don't want to implement the interface `java.sql.Connection`.

It appears to me as mocking, but I'm asking here to seek for alternatives before I pursue the idea of using a mock library (that I don't know much about either).

I'd rather avoid using `val c: java.sql.Connection = null` and I really wish I could use a fluent interface with all the methods mocked but one I want to provide.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. FYI, mocks use reflection to mimic the interface of a given type, but they are not actual instances of that type.

Comment: Thanks! How would you go about having an instance or something that would behave as such?

Comment: Using mocks would the way to go, that's what they are for, essentially. Using an existing framework would easier, obviously, rather than trying do that by yourself from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can but it may force on you some implications:

```
trait MySqlConnection {
  def c: SqlConnection 
}
```

and now:

```
val msqlC = new MySqlConnection {
  var c: SqlConnection = _
}
```

For my dummy `SqlConnection` defined as `class SqlConnection` it works.

Comment: For a trait with a single method I can provide an implementation at assignment, but what about the traits with 5 defs/vals? The question is about finding a way to provide little to no implementation at all. Possible?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible with `val`s. `Def`s are automatically overriden by `val` `var` `def` .

Comment: Is repeating `var` with `_` the only solution you'd offer for my case (excluding `val`s)?

Comment: For the moment I don't have any idea. Sorry.